# Building a static library with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods

I am trying to build a static library that has different dependencies (AFNetworking for example) specified in a Podfile. I don't want the dependencies to be included in the final static library (call libMyProject.a), I just want to link against them and then create a MyProject.Podspec file where I can put the same dependencies.

The problem is that when I build libMyProject.a the libPods.a is linked and included, so that if I distribute libMyProject.a and other people integrates it in a project which uses some of the same dependencies it will have duplicate symbols issues.

How can I link against the libPods.a lib but not include it in libMyProject.a? It should work just like linking with other existing frameworks.

Thanks!

Comment: If the answer you added below is the correct one, mark it as such so this question no longer shows as open.

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by removing the libPods.a lib from the section "Link Binary With Libraries" in Build Phases.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer and I elaborate on my solution to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17869668/106703

Comment: Is there some smart way to automate this removal? I've tried multiple approaches with no success.

Comment: @Wilmar, see my answer for automated removal (or more specifically, how to avoid adding it in the first place).

Answer (score 6):

Whilst manually removing the libPods.a from the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase does indeed work, the real answer is to not let it get added there in the first place.

The reason it is added is because the pod install command is finding the static library target as one of its targets to link with. This could be because it is the first target in the list (cocoapods' implementation causes it to pick the first one if you haven't explicitly specified targets) or it could be because you have explicitly stated it in the 'link_with' section.

The answer I find is to use the link_with section of the Podfile to explicitly state your targets, and *omit the static library target*.

The pods project is still created, and your dependencies brought into there as you'd expect, but the libPods.a isn't added to the build phase of your static library.

The only problem is what to put into the link_with section, if not your static library. If you have other targets that you do want to link with (an iPhone app target for instance) that's a good choice. But if your only real target is your static library, you need a little workaround.

My successful strategy so far has been to create a static library target (yes, a separate one from your *main* static library) and call it "Dummy". Specify this target in your Podfile's link_with section.

It is a little distasteful, granted, but it does work.

```
platform :ios, '5.1.1'

link_with ['Dummy']

pod 'AFNetworking', '= 1.3.1'
```

Comment: This works well but you might also need to set the configuration of you static library target to `Pods.xcconfig`, otherwise the headers of the dependent libraries cannot be used in your static library.

Comment: You may need to manually add the Cocoapods-generated xcconfig (e.g., Pods.debug.xcconfig) to your Xcode project's configuration (Project > Info > Configurations) for header search to work. I did get this pattern to work, but I came up with [another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30057642/686385).

Answer (score 1):

Referenced libraries are not (by default) included in the static library product. The linker conflict you're seeing is more likely the result of both your static library and the client app both using the default (implicit) Pod target.

Every Cocoapods-generated target includes a "Pods-*target*-dummy.m" file that is compiled into the product; if you use the default Pods target, it's just called "Pods-dummy.m". When both the library and client use the default target, the identical symbols produced from compiling the dummy files will cause a link error.

I tried a variation of [Craig's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21608948/686385) myself, and found that the `link_with` statement is also responsible for hooking up the xcconfig generated by Cocoapods, which provides the compiler flags that control the header search path. You can add the xcconfig (or the header search path project settings) manually, of course, but I went looking for a repeatable solution for my team.

My solution is to create an explicit target for the library, with a name that is unlikely to cause conflicts with a client project (for example, the name of the library):

```
target 'XYZLibrary' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '2.5.2'
    ...
end
```

You can include a `link_with` statement within the `target` block if the name of the static library target (in your Xcode project) is different, but if there's only one target, I usually prefer to use the same name in both places, making `link_with` unnecessary.

If you have a unit test target, create two separate targets. (I currently `def` a set of common pods that are used in both targets, since abstract targets are not currently an option, but they may be one day.) It looks like this:

```
def common_pods
  pod 'AFNetworking', '2.5.2'
end

target 'XYZLibrary' do
  common_pods
end

target 'XYZLibraryTests' do
  common_pods
end
```

The key is to not have any `pod` elements in the root of the Podfile, so that Cocoapods won't generate a default target. That way, each product gets a unique "Pods-*target*-dummy.m", and there's no conflict when those object files are linked together.

Comment: Heh, just found that [eliasbagley posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23370841/686385) the same solution already!