# What is the real meaning of the link_with in the Podfile?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My question is, I don't know what really happens after I use the `link_with`  in my Podfile so I don't know when and where to use it.I have read the [guide](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with) but the description is to brief to know the meaning of `link_with`.

After my test, I know that if I use `link_with` without `target` in my Podfile the default Pods library *libPods.a* will be linked to the targets quoted by the `link_with`.But if there is `target` in the Podfile the `link_with` looks like making no use any more.

Besides this, the official guide don't mention where to write the `link_with`,so when I saw `link_with 'Dummy'` in the `target` block I was very confused.

Can anybody explain when and where to write the `link_with` and the reason using the `link_with 'Dummy'` ?(I just know that it is used to solve duplicated symbols in the library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1: link_with vs. target:

Keyword here is:

> If **no explicit target** is specified...

`target:` and `link_with` are mutually exclusive: use one *or* the other.

- Use `link_with` as a shortcut if **all** your targets use the same Pods dependencies.
- Use `target:` to specify individual Pods dependencies for each target. *Note:* `link_with` keyword is *ignored* when 1 or more `target:` are defined ; `target:` takes precedence.

## Question 2: link_with 'Dummy'

> Building a static library with cocoapods

This is a workaround to prevent a Pod from being included in a Static Library, so that said Pod in not part of said Lib. By adding an actual target named 'Dummy' to your main Static Library project, and specifying that your Pods ought to be linked against 'Dummy', you fool Cocoapods into fetching the desired Pods, yet not include them in your Static Library. Related post here: [Building a static library with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092822/building-a-static-library-with-cocoapods).

Comment: Thanks a lot ~But I saw a Podfile use `link_with` like this:`target 'static' do link_wth 'Dummy' end `,is it the right method to use?

Answer (score 7):

As [document](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with) says it's not meaningful to use with one target project :

> If no explicit target is specified, then the Pods target will be
>   linked with the first target in your project. So if you only have one
>   target you do not need to specify the target to link with.

For example I have multi target application, and here is first few lines of my Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '9.3'

workspace 'MyApplication'
link_with 'target1', 'target2', 'target3', 'target4'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.2'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
```

etc.

meaningful to use here because if you don't use "target2, target3 and  target4" will give errors when you build it. So thats why we use it.

Alternatively you can specify pods for each target and add shared pods for common pods like this :

```
platform :ios, '9.3'

workspace 'MyApplication'

def shared_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.2'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.0.0'
end

target :target1, :exclusive => true do
  shared_pods
end 

target :target2, :exclusive => true do
  shared_pods
  pod 'Mantle'
end

target :target3, :exclusive => true do
  shared_pods
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
end 

target :target4, :exclusive => true do
  shared_pods
end
```

is everything clear now @Yujie Ren?

Also, check [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target) for `:exclusive => true do` meaning.

Comment: Excellent `def shared_pods ... end` suggestion.

Comment: thanks a lot~And in your Podfile, if I remove the `:exclusive=>true ` of the target2 then other targets can import the Mantle library ,is it right?

Comment: you're welcome @Yujie Ren. Yes, for exclusive you understand correct. Check here for cocoapods document example : https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target

Comment: Thank you, @Lancelot de la Mare

Comment: @Yujie Ren Is there anything I can help?

Comment: Last question~I saw a Podfile use `link_with` like this:`target 'static' do link_wth 'Dummy' end` ,is it the right method to use?

Comment: I never try but if it's work why not, but what I understand you can make same thing with shared_pods, this way will be more easy to read I guess