# Kiwi and CocoaPods with a static shared library

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, kiwi

I have a workspace with 3 projects:

- MyApp
- Common
- Pods

Common is a common library that MyApp depends on. I'd like to setup CocoaPods and Kiwi to work correctly in this project. How do I go about this?

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/16472563/62, but when I try to follow this approach, I get an error when building MyApp before I even try adding Kiwi:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods
```

Here's the repo on GitHub: https://github.com/lyahdav/cocoapods_kiwi_shared_library

My Podfile is:

```
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'Common' do
  xcodeproj 'Common/Common.xcodeproj'

  pod 'AFNetworking'
  pod 'Reachability'

  target 'MyApp', :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a working solution for this. Here's the Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'

xcodeproj 'MyApp'

pod 'CupertinoYankee', '~> 1.0'

target :MyAppTests, :exclusive => true do
    pod 'Kiwi/XCTest'
end

target :Common, :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'Common/Common'
    pod 'CupertinoYankee', '~> 1.0'
end

target :CommonTests, :exclusive => true do
    xcodeproj 'Common/Common'
    pod 'Kiwi/XCTest'
end
```

This example Podfile shows both MyApp and Common configured to use Kiwi for tests and they can both use pods (CupertinoYankee in this example).

I did manually have to configure in Xcode that MyApp links with Common with these steps:

1. In MyApp project settings > MyApp target > Build Phases > Link
   Binary With Libraries > add libCommon.a
2. In MyApp project settings > Build Settings > User Header Search Paths > add `${SRCROOT}/Common/Common/**`

This repo has a working example: https://github.com/lyahdav/cocoapods_kiwi_shared_library

The only slightly annoying thing I didn't manage to figure out was if there's a way to not duplicate each pod that I want to use both in MyApp and Common. If anyone has a solution that does all of what my solution does and solves that, I'll gladly mark it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Posted [as an edit by anonymous user](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12788501). Here's his answer:

---

I have forked the repository and made few changes for new cocoapods versions to make it still working.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'

project 'MyApp'

target :MyApp do
    pod 'CupertinoYankee', '~> 1.0'
end

target :MyAppTests do
    pod 'Kiwi/XCTest'
end

target :Common do
    project 'Common/Common'
    pod 'CupertinoYankee', '~> 1.0'
end

target :CommonTests do
    project 'Common/Common'
    pod 'Kiwi/XCTest'
end
```

https://github.com/chrishunterkiller/cocoapods_kiwi_shared_library

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix the setup you have, but if I were you I would make `Common` into its own Pod.  Pods can be private and just stored in GitHub as a repo.  Of course, you need a podspec for `Common` but I built a sample to test that setup for our build service and it took me less than 30 mins to get it right.

Then in your Podfile for MyApp, you do something like this:

`pod 'Common', :git => 'git@github.com:lyahdav/Common.git', :commit => 'a1b2c3d'`

And `AFNetworking` and `Reachability` can be referenced in the podspec of `Common` (assuming that's the right dependency).

This setup also allows you to include `Common` in whatever other apps you're building without having to embed the code.  Again, making assumptions about what you're trying to achieve, so add more detail to the question if that's not right.

Comment: The issue I have with this approach is it would mean the Common Pod would be in its own repo. This would mean I'd have two repos to maintain which seems like unnecessary overhead in my situation. Or is there a way to alleviate that? I want to be able to split apart the Common code mainly for separation of concerns and so I can TDD quicker on the Common library. Right now when I want to run a test related to the Common code, it has to build the entire project, which takes about 20 seconds each time because of its size. The Common code alone would build much quicker.

Comment: You could make `Common` and `MyApp` both into child directories in a top-level directory for your repo and use the `:path` approach to referencing the Common pod, instead of `:git` (see @Rivera 's answer). That approach doesn't give you the benefit of isolating the `Common` codebase for use in other apps, but if that's not your objective, might be simpler. I lean towards smaller single-purpose repos, but it's just personal preference.

Comment: I'm trying the `:path` approach, but I'm stuck on how to create a Kiwi test suite for the Common project that I can run from the same Xcode workspace as `MyApp`. I tried creating a new project as part of the workspace that has a dependency on the Pods project and I tried writing tests there (using XTest for now) that exercise code in the Common project, but I get a linker error saying `undefined symbols` for the class I'm trying to use in my tests. Any idea how this bit should be set up?

Comment: I would expect that the tests for Common would be in the Common project. Is there a reason not to do it that way? Any manipulation of the MyApp workspace to tell it about Common is breaking the isolation that you created by moving the Common stuff into a Pod and will likely result in a fragile config. I'm happy to jump on a chat if that will help instead of creating a huge comment thread.

Comment: Sorry for neglecting this for a while, I just posted an answer that solved my specific problem. I wanted the Common tests to be part of the Common project, but I wanted to be able to run them from the same Xcode workspace as MyApp. I achieved that in my solution (by switching to the Common scheme and running tests).

Answer (score 0):

You could hack a solution that may get broken again, or better yet as Common is your library, start using CocoaPods for your Common library as well.

It will show up as a local "Dvelopment Pod", which means that you can directly edit the library code as well.

To begin easily just create a Common.podspec at the root folder:

`$ pod lib create Common`

Then just edit the minimum required [parameters](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html), such as `platform`, `source_files`, `requires_arc` and `dependency` if any.

You can take a look at how your library looks as you change it (and compare it to what you had with your manually created Common library):

`$ pod lib lint --no-clean Common.podspec`

Finally remove the no-longer needed Common from your workspace and add this to your Podfile:

`pod 'Common', :path => '../Relative/Path/To/CommonSources/'`

It will take you no more than 30 minutes and you'll learn many things in the process.

Next you could take a look at making [private](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) pod repositories.

Comment: I'm liking this approach, except I'm not seeing how I'd create a separate Kiwi test suite for the Common library that I can run in the same Xcode workspace. I'm going to experiment with different solutions now, but do you have any ideas? Should there be a new test target in the Pods project? A new test project in my workspace?

Comment: Most likely you'll need two projects and two `Podfile`s (and thus two accompanying `Pods` directories and two CocoaPods-generated Workplaces), one for your App, and one to test your `Common` library. If both projects had very close requirements then you could try to have a single project with two targets and juggle requirements in the Podfile like here: http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target.